# pack. Prelude.show for Text

Tags: string, haskell

```
show :: Show a => a -> Text
show = pack . Prelude.show
```

In this [blog](http://www.tazj.in/en/1335123720), I see `show` is overwritten. What does `pack` method provide on top of `Prelude`. The author has put, this is for `Text` instead of `Strings`.

Most other languages have `String` and `Buffer` as data structures  . But what is `Text` in haskell?

Answer (score 1):

That type comes from the `text` package, in the module `Data.Text`. It's a more efficient and compliant structure for Unicode text than `String`, since a `String` is just a `[Char]`.  Lists are great data structures, but not the most efficient structure for text manipulation.  Haskell also has the `ByteString` type from the `bytestring` package in the `Data.ByteString` module and submodules which represents efficient buffers.

Answer (score 0):

Haskell's default `String` type is flexible, but rather inefficient. `Text` is more like what other programming languages have — an *array* of characters, rather than a linked list of them.

Neither of these types is much like a string buffer or string builder that you find in other languages.